# On the angle subtended between the angular momentum vector and the applied field for a single spin

Tags: physical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

[image]

According to Dr James Keeler of Cambridge University in one of his lectures at Queensland University, the angle theta can be *any* angle, but I struggle to see how this is true. There are only a certain number of *I* values that nuclei take and as illustrated in the figure above, each magnetic quantum number corresponds to a fixed theta. Is my logic flawed?

Comment: It depends whether you are talking about a single spin or a collection.

Comment: a single spin. I'd be interested to know about the collection case too.

Comment: As an aside, the coordinate system you drew is left-handed. There's nothing intrinsically wrong with that, but conventionally people work with right-handed systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that a given value of $m_I$ and $I$ does correspond to one single value of the angle $\theta$. For the most commonly used nuclei in NMR spectroscopy, the "allowed" values are $I = 1/2$ and $m_I = \pm 1/2$. The two states are commonly labelled $\alpha$ and $\beta$; these are the eigenstates of the angular momentum projection operator $\hat{I}_z$, such that

$$\begin{align}
\hat{I}_z|\alpha\rangle &= \frac{1}{2}|\alpha\rangle \\
\hat{I}_z|\beta\rangle &= -\frac{1}{2}|\beta\rangle
\end{align}$$

(treating $\hbar \equiv 1$). The problem is that you are assuming that the wavefunction (of a spin) can *only* be in an eigenstate. **This is not true.** It is perfectly valid, and indeed necessary (see below), to have states that are superpositions of eigenstates. In general, a spin can have *any* state

$$|\psi\rangle = c_\alpha |\alpha\rangle + c_\beta |\beta\rangle$$

where $|c_\alpha|^2 + |c_\beta|^2 = 1$ (normalisation), and in general the coefficients are time-dependent (see below). This is no longer an eigenstate of $\hat{I}_z$, and consequently is no longer well-described by one value of $m_I$, or for that matter, $\theta$. But that is not intrinsically a problem. The only circumstance in which a wavefunction *must* be described by an eigenstate is immediately following an observation, where the wavefunction $|\psi\rangle$ [collapses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse) to the eigenstate $|i\rangle$ with probability $|c_i|^2$. Otherwise, superposition states are entirely consistent with quantum mechanics.

---

A more generalised example is to think of the time-independent Schrödinger equation:

$$\hat{H}|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle$$

which is an eigenvalue equation for the Hamiltonian, $\hat{H}$. It is true that only eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are *admissible solutions to this equation*. But that does not mean that the only *physically permissible states* for the system are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. The time-independent SE only governs systems that are not evolving in time, or *stationary states*. We need something else to describe systems that *do* evolve with time, which is the time-dependent Schrödinger equation:

$$\hat{H}|\Psi\rangle = i\hbar\frac{\partial |\Psi\rangle}{\partial t}$$

The most general solution to the TDSE is, indeed, a superposition of stationary states (the Internet has lots of more thorough explanations, or read Griffiths' *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*):

$$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_i c_i \exp\left(-\frac{iE_it}{\hbar}\right) |\psi_i\rangle $$

where the $c_i$'s are time-independent. Indeed, it is *necessary* for us to have superposition states, because this allows the coefficients of each eigenstate to evolve in a time-dependent fashion (because of the exponential term, which evolves at different frequencies for different eigenstates). If a system is prepared in an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, then it can *never* evolve into another eigenstate (the exponential evolves, but if there is only one eigenstate, it is no more than a simple phase factor).

This might not seem immediately relevant for NMR, but recall that the (free) Hamiltonian in NMR is simply $-\gamma B_0 \hat{I}_z$. So, the eigenstates of $\hat{I}_z$, $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\beta\rangle$, are also the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. If we *never* had superposition eigenstates, then the spins would simply sit there forever and do nothing.*

---

* As long as the Hamiltonian doesn't change. But if you change the Hamiltonian, say from $\hat{H}_0$ to $\hat{H}_1$, then the eigenstates change, and so your system (which was originally an eigenstate of $\hat{H}_0$ is no longer an eigenstate of $\hat{H}_1$). Indeed, it would be in a superposition of eigenstates of $\hat{H}_1$, and would evolve in time according to the TDSE, so it doesn't invalidate any of the preceding discussion.

Comment: I think your answer (and mine) might benefit from inclusion of a description of how the observed angle $\theta$ depends on the quantum state (or coherence).

Comment: @BuckThorn, I considered going into it but felt too lazy...! Imo it would require describing density matrices, Pauli matrices and the Bloch sphere (I may be overcomplicating it, of course). NMR theory uses these tools regularly to describe bulk magnetisation, less so for a single spin. But quantum computing uses Bloch spheres for single spins. Maybe if I have time...

Comment: @orthocresol I appreciate the technical correctness of your response, but I must admit that I am not particularly au fait with QM. From what I understand of your answer, the angle theta is constant for an angular momentum vector of a spin with a certain magnetic quantum number only when it's observed. When not being observed it can take any value of theta. This is essentially the Copenhagen interpretation. Is this correct? The bulk magnetization vector can take many values of theta when observed as it's an average of all the thetas of each individual spin. Is this also correct?

Comment: @ETS, that’s a pretty accurate summary.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetization is composed of the sum of dipole moments associated with individual spins:

$$\vec{M}=\sum_i \vec{\mu}_i$$

and the component along the magnetizing field (assumed to lie along the z axis) is

$$\begin{align}M_z&= \left( \sum_i \vec{\mu}_i\right)_z \\ &=  \sum_i \mu_{iz}\end{align}$$

Since the individual dipole moment components along z take on discrete values (are quantized, ie for the homonuclear case $\vec{\mu}_{iz}=\gamma\hbar m_z $) we can write

$$M_z =  \gamma\hbar\sum_i m_{i} \tag{1}$$

where the symbols have their usual meanings. Since the sum extends over a large number of spins $i$, the resulting magnetization can for practical purposes be regarded as taking on a continuous range of values, even if the z-component of individual spins is discretely valued.

Comment: You are correct, except that individual spins need not *always* take quantised values of $m_z$. The bulk magnetisation is a valuable point to bring up though, especially in the context of NMR.

Comment: @orthocresol in the presence of an external field in an NMR experiment the z component of each spin is assumed quantized, as far as I am aware.

Comment: I've gone into more detail about that in my answer; it's not true that individual spins must be either up or down. This is something that is always taught at the introductory level (probably to make things easier), but is inconsistent with QM, where superposition is a key concept.

Comment: @orthocresol that's a good point but it brings to mind the confusing distinction between superpositions and coherences. In general measurement is associated with quantization along a measurement axis. Note that since I limit discussion to $M_z$ afaik equation 1 is general. Also, I am trying to explain how an observable macroscopic property could have a continuum of values while made up of discrete entities, but thanks for bringing this to my attention, I will have to reread my copy of Cavanagh.

Comment: *"how an observable macroscopic property could have a continuum of values"* I understand, and that point is entirely valid (hence why I said it's valuable!). It's just that OP is likely confused over the single-spin case. Modern NMR textbooks, like that of Keeler (and also Levitt's *Spin Dynamics*), point out that superpositions are allowed and that individual spins only being in up / down states is mostly a myth. I'm not sure if Cavanagh mentions it (I've only perused small sections of the book), but I wouldn't be surprised if he does, too.

Comment: Also re. *"measurement is associated with quantization along a measurement axis"*: you are correct about that too. But I don't think just placing the spins in a magnetic field constitutes a measurement; a measurement would be something more like a Stern–Gerlach apparatus, where you probe each individual spin to see whether it's up or down (or to be more precise, whether it collapses into up or down).

Comment: @orthocresol In section 2.1.4 of the 1st edition they go into the time dependence of the *expectation value* of the component along a particular axis of the dipole moment  of a single spin, approaching the problem as you do, and an angle $\theta$ can be defined on the basis of this (but is not defined in that section). Immediately after that they jump into the density matrix treatment. As I mentioned, I need to reread, but discussion in terms of the evolution of single spins (while important) is not sufficient to understand magnetization.

Comment: Re measurement: I think NMR qualifies! :-)

Comment: In NMR we only detect bulk transverse magnetisation; this doesn't collapse the wavefunctions of the individual spins, it only collapses the total wavefunction to one which agrees with the measurement. Sorry, but even though I fully agree with you that bulk magnetisation is the physically important quantity, I cannot upvote now because I don't agree with the treatment of quantisation. I do very much appreciate your good-natured replies, though.

Comment: @orthocresol That's ok. The form collapse takes always depends on what you measure. I don't see why NMR should be any different.